Persistent Database Connection Issues on GoDaddy VPS with Laravel 9.19 and PHP 8.0 After Server Rebuild
I have a connection issue on my VPS from GoDaddy. It is a site based on Laravel 9.19 and PHP 8.0. The problem started after we decided to rebuild the server. Since then, I have had issues with the database connection where, after making several queries, the connection breaks and then restores after a few seconds. How could I solve this?
I have attempted several troubleshooting steps to resolve the persistent database connection issues on my GoDaddy VPS, which is running Laravel 9.19 and PHP 8.0. Here is a summary of what I have tried:
Updated the .env File:
Ensured that all database credentials are correctly specified.
Verified the presence and correct configuration of the .env file.
Expected: Proper loading of environment variables and stable database connections.
Installed and Configured phpdotenv:
Installed the vlucas/phpdotenv package using Composer.
Loaded environment variables using Dotenv::createImmutable().
Expected: Correct loading of environment variables and consistent database connections.
Checked and Adjusted File Permissions:
Ensured correct permissions for the .env file.
Expected: Environment variables to be read correctly, resulting in stable connections.
Tested Direct Database Connections:
Created a script to repeatedly test the database connection.
Expected: Continuous stable connections without interruption.
Added Detailed Logging:
Implemented error logging to capture connection issues.
Expected: Identification of specific errors causing connection breaks.
Checked Server and Database Configuration:
Verified server and database settings for any misconfigurations or limitations.
Expected: Configuration adjustments to resolve connection instability.
Despite these efforts, the issue persists where the database connections break after several queries and restore after a few seconds. I was expecting these steps to provide a stable and continuous connection to the database without interruptions.

are you sure you have configured the database server correctly and allotted enough system resources?

What message does the connection break with? What exactly happens?

How would the proper configuration look?
